# Windows Server: Import saved log file into existing log

Tags: windows, logging, logfile

OS: Windows Server 2012 Standard

I saved off the Application, Security and System logs and accidentally cleared the logs.  How do I import those saved logs back into the existing Windows Logs?

I have tried saving the saved logs as XML and trying to import it back into the log as a custom view but that does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Using the process from this site (https://davidsottimano.com/combine-files-using-windows-command-prompt/), you copy the logs/event files into one directory then use the code:

```
type *.evtx > <Your Log Name Here>.evtx
```

[image]